Custom environment variables provided in Kubernetes spark job is not getting picked up
This is yaml of my spark job:
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: operatordc1
  namespace: spark
spec:
  type: Java
  mode: cluster
  image: "xiotxpcdevcr.azurecr.io/spark-custom:release-8.0"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  imagePullSecrets:
    - mdsp-secret-spark
  mainClass: "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"
  mainApplicationFile: "local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/operatordc1.jar" # Ensure this is the correct path within your Docker image
  sparkVersion: "3.4.2"
  restartPolicy:
    type: Never
  driver:
    env:
      - name: spring.profiles.active
        value: azure,secured  
    cores: 4
    coreLimit: "4000m"
    memory: "4096m"
    javaOptions: >-
      -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///log4j2.xml
      --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
      --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
      --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
      --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
      --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
      --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
      --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
      -XX:+UseG1GC
      -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
      -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
      -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=100M
      -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
      -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=256m
      -Xms1024m
      -Dlog4j.debug
    labels:
      version: "3.4.2"
    serviceAccount: spark
  executor:
    cores: 4
    instances: 1
    memory: "4096m"
    javaOptions: >-
      -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///log4j2.xml
      -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=100M
      -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
      -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=256m
      --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
      -Dlog4j.debug
    labels:
      version: "3.4.2"
    serviceAccount: spark
    env:
      - name: spring.profiles.active
        value: "azure,secured"    
  sparkConf:
    "spark.driver.userClassPathFirst": "true"
    "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst": "true"
    "spark.driver.memory": "4096m"
    "spark.executor.memory": "4096m"
    "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "true"

when I am describing the pod , I am getting only spark operator provided env values :
Environment:
  SPARK_USER:                 root
  SPARK_APPLICATION_ID:       spark-699c7647354544e293cc2c12cda9e88e
  SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS:   (v1:status.podIP)
  SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS:           /var/data/spark-c6e072fb-2e09-4a07-8c58-0365eda4f362
  SPARK_CONF_DIR:             /opt/spark/conf

It is missing
name: spring.profiles.active
        value: "azure,secured"    

I am following this documentation : https://github.com/kubeflow/spark-operator/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md
what else I need to do so that environment variables provided by me are picked by driver

can you try changing the environment variable name? like use underscores to separate words and use capital case?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
